# Insert en Tablas

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<title>Cargando...</title>
<?
session_start();
$num_solicitud= $_POST['num_solicitud'];
$num_propuesta= $_POST['num_propuesta'];
$fecha_solicitud=$_POST['fecha_solicitud'];
$cod_asegurado=$_POST['asegurado'];
$nom_asegurado=$_POST['nom_asegurado'];
$rut=$_POST['rut'];
$dv_rut=$_POST['dv_rut'];
$telefono_uno=$_POST['telefono_uno'];
$telefono_dos=$_POST['telefono_dos'];
$email_cliente=$_POST['email_cliente'];
$direccion_comercial=$_POST['direccion_comercial'];
$cod_region=$_POST['regiones'];
$cod_provincia=$_POST['provincias'];
$cod_localidad=$_POST['ciudades'];
$cod_comuna=$_POST['comunas'];
$direccion_riesgo=$_POST['direccion_riesgo'];
$tipo_prog_mantencion=$_POST['tipo_prog_mantencion'];
$tipo_siniestros=$_POST['tipo_siniestros'];
$persona_contacto=$_POST['persona_contacto'];
$giro_actividad=$_POST['giro_actividad'];
$jornada_laboral=$_POST['jornada_laboral'];
$num_empleados=$_POST['num_empleados'];
$tiempo_negocio=$_POST['tiempo_negocio'];
$tiempo_ubicacion=$_POST['tiempo_ubicacion'];
$relacion_laboral=$_POST['relacion_laboral'];
$otras_ubicaciones=$_POST['otras_ubicaciones'];
$nom_corredor=$_POST['corredor'];
$ema_corredor=$_POST['email_corredor'];
$rut_corredor=$_POST['rut_corredor'];
$dv_corredor=$_POST['dv_corredor'];
$cia=$_SESSION['idcia'];
include '../include/conexion.php';
//echo $persona_contacto;

if ($cod_asegurado == "1"){
    echo "Valido, sigue tu camino";
    $insertar_clientes = ("INSERT INTO clientes(id_cliente,asegurado,rut,dv_rut,
                           telefono_uno,telefono_dos,corredor,email_corredor,
                           rut_corredor,dv_corredor,email_cliente,direccion_comercial,
                           giro_actividad,jornada_laboral,num_empleados,tiempo_negocio,
                           tiempo_ubicacion,relacion_laboral,otras_ubicaciones,id_cia) 
                           VALUES (NULL,'$cod_asegurado','$rut','$dv_rut','$telefono_uno',
                           '$telefono_dos','$nom_corredor','$ema_corredor','$rut_corredor',
                           '$dv_corredor','$email_cliente','$direccion_comercial','$giro_actividad',
                           '$jornada_laboral','$num_empleados','$tiempo_negocio','$tiempo_ubicacion',
                           '$relacion_laboral','$otras_ubicaciones','$cia')");
    $insertar_cliente_s = mysql_query($insertar_clientes,$conexion);
    //recibo el último id
    $cod_asegurado = mysql_insert_id($conexion);    
} else {
    $insertar_clientes = ("UPDATE clientes SET asegurado='$cod_asegurado',rut='$rut',dv_rut='$dv_rut',telefono_uno='$telefono_uno',telefono_dos='$telefono_dos',corredor='$nom_corredor',email_corredor='$ema_corredor',rut_corredor='$rut_corredor',dv_corredor='$dv_corredor',email_cliente='$email_cliente',direccion_comercial='$direccion_comercial',persona_contacto='$persona_contacto',giro_actividad='$giro_actividad',jornada_laboral='$jornada_laboral',num_empleados='$num_empleados',relacion_laboral='$relacion_laboral',otras_ubicaciones='$otras_ubicaciones',id_cia='$cia' WHERE id_cliente='$cod_asegurado'");
    $insertar_cliente_s = mysql_query($insertar_clientes,$conexion);
}

$insertara = ("INSERT INTO inspeccion(num_solicitud,num_propuesta,direccion_riesgo,persona_contacto,cod_region,cod_provincia,cod_comuna,cod_localidad,tipo_prog_mantencion,tipo_siniestros,fecha_solicitud,id_cliente,estado,id_cia) VALUES ('$num_solicitud','$num_propuesta','$direccion_riesgo','$persona_contacto','$cod_region','$cod_provincia','$cod_comuna','$cod_localidad','$tipo_prog_mantencion','$tipo_siniestros','$fecha_solicitud','$cod_asegurado','SOLICITADA','$cia')");
$insert_inspeccion = mysql_query($insertara,$conexion);


if($insertara){?>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="2; URL=registros_in.php?cod=3">
<?
}else{?>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="2; URL=registros_in.php?cod=4">
<?
} 
?>
<center><img src="../img/cargando.gif" width="400" height="400" /></center>
```

Buenas tengo un problema con el insert y con update a tabla clientes. Favor necesito de su conocimiento para salir de este agujero. De antemano gracias

Comment: https://pastebin.com/1mAtWbHY Ahi esta el codigo

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Pega el codigo necesario aqui. Muchas personas no tienen o no quieren acceder a esos sitios, ademas despues de un tiempo esos links dejan de servir. Mira tambien [mcve]

Comment: Podrias explicar cual es el problema que tienes?

Comment: Que el Insert clientes no esta grabando los datos que ingreso

Comment: recibis algun error? por favor podrias revisar los links que te pase, es muy dificil si no das toda la informacion completa de lo que esta pasando.

Comment: De hecho no da error de ningun tipo, va a la pagina que le corresponde y me indica que se inserta correctamente, pero al ir a la BD no hay nada de lo que registre

Comment: Quita los paréntesis de las consultas. Aparte revisa todos los valores que recibes, puede que alguno vaya vacío

Comment: y probaste hacer un insert basico en la BD desde este codigo, a ver si el problema es precisamente el insert?

Comment: gbianchi Si probe directo en la base y lo guarda, por lo que sintaxis no creo que sea

Comment: Aparte porque haces un `if` a esta variable si únicamente es un **string** `insertara`

Comment: la variable insertara es la que realiza el manejo de caso, cod 3 y cod 4 es para ingreso y error respectivamente

Comment: Si entiendo, pero lo único que tiene es un **string** la consulta la haces pero con la variable `insert_inspeccion`

Comment: ¿Ya quitaste los paréntesis como se te dijo, aquí: `$insertar_clientes = ("INSERT INTO...`  y lo mismo en el `UPDATE`?